# How Can We See The References Option on Windows Forms App in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, reference, windows-forms-designer

I am having a hard time to understand why references option is not appearing in the solution explorer when i open a Windows Forms App. If i open a console app, it's there.

What am i missing? Enlighten me please.

Comment: what kind of project did you start?

Comment: there  are two that I see - one with .net and the other net framework.  You want the net framework one then

Comment: After i posted this i realized that the problem was that i did create a non .Net windows forms app. When i created a new Windows Forms(.NET Framework) project., references option was there. Thank you for your effort @duerzd696.

Answer (score 0):

There are two that I see - one with .net and the other net framework. You want the net framework one then.